# AWS creation failed: Service already exists. (Service: AWSServiceDiscovery; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ServiceAlreadyExists; Request ID)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS and encountered some problem while trying to create a EC2 service in a ECS cluster.

I was able to successfully create a brand new service (`service1`) in `cluster1`, but afterwards, I decided to delete `cluster1` and create `cluster2`. The problem came when I try to re-create `service1` in `cluster2`. Whenever I try to add the service, I will get the following error

```
creation failed: Service already exists. (Service: AWSServiceDiscovery; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ServiceAlreadyExists; Request ID: d854025e-ebcc-11e8-84ab-b3bac906f2ef)
```

How can I resolve this problem? I have tried deregistering the task definition but it didn't work. `cluster1` has been deleted and there are no services in `cluster2`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a service with a different name?

Comment: i thought about it but i would like to find a way to remove the residues from the previous service @MohitKumar

Comment: Haow have you created the cluster : using the CLI or the AWS Console? If it is the second, please make sure you have no services whatsoever: > In this case, after the cluster is deleted, you should delete any remaining AWS CloudFormation stack resources or Auto Scaling groups associated with the cluster to avoid incurring any future charges for those resources.

Comment: @DJ_ have you checked the cloudformation stack for cluster1 if it exists or not ?

Comment: @DJ_ it looks like you have created AWS Service with Fargate type?. If yes, when you created as Fargate and enabled Service Discovery for it then under Route 53, it has created entry under Hosted Zones(private, I guess)?. Then please go to Route 53 and delete/cleanup the ECS Service related domain zones.

Comment: @TenorFlyy may i know where i can find the auto scaling association group? i have checked AWS CloudFormation stack, only cluster2 is inside so i think the problem might not have come from there?

Comment: @imran do u mean Launch type? i created it as EC2.
under my Route 53 i have the following 

Domain Name : local.
type : Private
Recrod set count: 2
Commnet : Created by Route 53 Auto Naming

is this what u were refrering to ?

Comment: @DJ_ yep. the same thing. Usually, I create Service Discovery for Fargate type. But you might have created it for EC2. You need to clean up this but one issue I remember is you cannot do it via UI. You need to use AWS CLI to delete the service discovery data from Route 53. Try from your end and let me know. If you need CLI command, I will paste sample one

Comment: @Imran how do i do it via cli? i have tried a few commands from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/index.html but none give me service discovery data

Comment: @DJ_ check the full answer I added.

Answer (score 30):

Here is full answer. When you created AWS ECS Service and you have also selected optional ServiceDiscovery for it as well which created an namespace(.local) and service(with same name as ECS Service) in Route53.

When you deleted ECS service & cluster, it won't automatically delete Route53 namespace/service entries. Now, you are getting `Service already exists` error since your new ECS Service matches with same name as ServiceDiscovery service. You have 3 options. 1. Clean up Route53 namespaces and services. 2. Re-use Route53 Service if you want to continue to use ServiceDiscovery feature. 3. Don't enable service discovery integration when you are creating ECS Service.

**Option 1** -

- You cannot delete Route53 ServiceDiscovery namespaces and service via Console. You will need to use AWS CLI.(Make sure you have configured CLI with AWS Keys same as the account where you have created ECS) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/servicediscovery/index.html
- List the Namespaces & Services with CLI using following commands and sample output you should get.
- `aws servicediscovery list-services`

> {
>       "Services": [
>           {
>               "Id": "srv-x4acveybedar32mv",
>               "Arn": "arn:aws:servicediscovery:us-east-1:1234567890:service/srv-x4acveybedar32mv",
>               "Name": "nginx"
>           }
>       ] }

- `aws servicediscovery list-namespaces`

> {
>       "Namespaces": [
>           {
>               "Id": "ns-3yd7pskwsxhwlq67",
>               "Arn": "arn:aws:servicediscovery:us-east-1:1234567890:namespace/ns-3yd7pskwsxhwlq67",
>               "Name": "local",
>               "Type": "DNS_PRIVATE"
>           }
>       ] }

- Delete the Service first with command. `aws servicediscovery delete-service --id "srv-x4acveybedar32mv"` . Result is empty response from CLI.
- Delete the namespace with command. `aws servicediscovery delete-namespace --id "ns-3yd7pskwsxhwlq67"`

> {
>       "OperationId": "s573v5dr62yee5d7vbfvsy5h65ybxmoh-jossalgs" }

- That's all. Now, you can re-create ECS services which you wanted.

## Note -

Sometimes, DNS cleanup operations will take couple of minutes to reflect properly so just give always few minutes before retrying.

**Option 2** -

- Re-use Route53 Services by selecting exiting one instead of creating with same name.

[image]

Comment: "You cannot delete Route53 ServiceDiscovery namespaces and service via Console" - that was a bit confusing for me. Thanks for the cli commands, worked like a charm

Comment: There used to be no option for deleting resources via console but there might be chance that they might have given feature now when deleting an ECS service.

Answer (score 1):

Should be delete from **AWS Cloud Map** Service.
The ECS Service discovery (DNS based) using AWS Cloud Map.

The use case of this problem. Using Service Discovery (DNS base), remove the ECS service without removing the Service Discovery (in the console you didn't set check box for delete entire from DNS private zone).
Trying to create service with existing entire.

AWS Cloud Map manage the Service Discovery (and DNS private zone).

Steps:
1. Go AWS Cloud Map [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjpU.png)
2. Delete enter image description here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OUjk.png)

Comment: Can you please specify the steps to do the delete or the code line/method to do it ?

Comment: Is it assist you?

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way I use is like this:

- First create another service (only if you do not have any other visible service) call it "temp-service"
- In the console Go into a service you have (temp or any...)
- now you have the full url in the browser
- So just replace the name of your service in the url with the service which is existing and is not visible
- The you can easily update it or delete that service

1:
https://ap-northeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/v2/clusters/mm-prod-ecs/services/mm-prod-aggregation-service/deployments?region=ap-northeast-1

2:
https://ap-northeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/v2/clusters/mm-prod-ecs/services/mm-prod-aggregation-service-lost/deployments?region=ap-northeast-1