# AWS / ECS - Namespace error when creating new service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

[AWS Service Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B3J1.png)

[Error when creating service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bxZG.png)

This is the error:

> creation failed: ns-4qwdjfuohtlmpiua (Service: AWSServiceDiscovery; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NamespaceNotFound; Request ID: 025b29e2-f73b-11e8-be57-33d9b1393e60)

I am setting `Namespace` to `create new private namespace`, but it doesn't appear to matter what I put, it will says `Created private namespace` with a random string.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this answer for any help in triaging. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434744/5030709. What is the namespace name you have already created?(local?) You might have to cleanup Route 53 name spaces.

Comment: Did you figure out a way around it?

Comment: I cleaned up Route 53 namespaces like mentioned above and nothing happened, I logged back into AWS the next day and it was no longer giving me the error.

Comment: I am having the same issue now in an account where this worked and now doesn't. There's no logs either. Route 53 won't let me clean up the namespaces either, and says they're in use by the failed service which I can't delete because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @JasonD you will need to delete Route53 Service first before deleting Namespace then it will allow. check the answer I referred, it has first step to delete services which returned by `list-services`.  @Tom, I had the similar behavior it turns out sometimes Route53 cleanup takes few minutes of time since its more of DNS operations cleanup.

Comment: I got the same error & after reading comments here realized that the randomnamespace it generated does not get created but the namespace I gave (say 'mylocal') gets created though the service creation itself fails. So when I recreate the service and find the mylocal namespace in the dropdown and this time the service creation succeeds with the correct namespace.

Answer (score 6):

The same thing just has happened to me, and the way to move past it was simply to go "Back" in the Console creation wizard, up to the "Service Discovery" section. I could find the namespace in the dropdown list, selected, and simply retried the service creation. It worked. I suspect there is a race condition between the namespace creation and verification.

Comment: Yep, this solved it. Seems like it takes some time for the namespace to be created. The first time I went back I ended up getting the error. Second time the namespace option was available in the namespace select field.